# how to pass a function into another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, function, dart

I have 2 classes ( a.dart and b.dart ) and I have a ***aFunction*** in *(Build Widget)* of the first class and I want to use this afunction into the second class , does enybody have an idea to solve that ? thanks

for example this the aFuntion in the first class :

```
              aFunction(){
            var text;
            if ( a > 10){
              text = Text('a bigger than 10');
            }
            else {
              text = Text('a is not bigger than 10');
            }
            return text;
          }
```

Comment: edit the post and add both classes code.

Comment: thanks for your answer , this is just a simple example of my problem , the actuall codes are more than 1000 lines

Comment: @behnami454 does  solve your case, if not it would be easier for other if you include minimal full snippet

Answer (score 2):

Your second class has to take a Function inside it's constructor.

```
class A {
  void test() {
    print("This is a function from class a");
  }
}

class B {
  Function function;

  B(this.function) {
    function.call();
  }
}
```

Example:

```
A classA = A();
B classB = B(classA.test);
```

Comment: I created a constructor as you said but I found your answer a bit confusing , can you please double check it , thanks

Comment: Which part do you not understand, I can help you better with that

Comment: Class A has the function, which is test(). Class B has a variable form type Function, which could be any function. If you create now an Object of class B, you can pass in any function which will be called in the constructor. I'll edit my answer with an example,